How to Prevent Default Player Hand from Appearing in UE5 Minimal Level?
I am new to Unreal Engine 5 and currently working on debugging at the driver level, which requires an environment with the utmost simplicity. To achieve this, I started with one of the template levels, deleted all unnecessary elements, and retained only a flat quad, the player, and a directional light. For reference, I’ve attached images of my current outliner, showcasing all the actors present in the scene.

However, when I press the play button, the player’s hand appears on the screen, which is not part of what I require. My goal is to have an environment with just the specified objects—nothing more. Below, I’ve included screenshots showing the unexpected results.

Could you please guide me on how to remove this hand element? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
Here is the AI answer to the problem
. Disable Auto Possession in Project Settings (Global Solution)
Go to Edit > Project Settings.
Search for "Default Pawn Class" under the Maps & Modes section.
Set it to None globally if you don’t want a player character to spawn in any level.

the AI answer made things worse, the player no longer spawns at the desired location. Additionally, I still want the ability to walk around the level, but without any extra visual elements—only the floor plane should be visible.
Thank you for all you help
